# Removing brackets and full stops from column in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following:

```
Column 1

London.(Sessions)
Birmingham.(Sessions)
Leeds.(Sessions)
```

How do I remove the strings so that I end up with this

```
Column 1

London
Birmingham
Leeds
```

So far I have used the following code:

```
stacked_sessions<-stacked_sessions%>%
 mutate_all(~gsub("(Sessions)", "", .))%>%
 mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all(.,'[\\.,]','')))
```

And I get and output of

```
London()
Birmingham()
Leeds()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything after `"."` ?

```
df$Column1 <- sub('\\..*', '', df$Column1)
df

#     Column1
#1     London
#2 Birmingham
#3      Leeds
```

The equivalent in `stringr` is using `str_remove` :

```
df$Column1 <- stringr::str_remove(df$Column1, "\\..*")
```

**data**

```
df <-  structure(list(Column1 = c("London.(Sessions)", "Birmingham.(Sessions)", 
"Leeds.(Sessions)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
df$Column1 <-  trimws(df$Column1, whitespace = '\\..*')
df$Column1
#[1] "London"     "Birmingham" "Leeds"
```

---

Or using `regmatches/regexpr` in `base R`

```
regmatches(df$Column1, regexpr("^[^.]+", df$Column1))
#[1] "London"     "Birmingham" "Leeds"
```

---

Or with `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$Column1, "^\\w+")  
#[1] "London"     "Birmingham" "Leeds"
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(Column1 = c("London.(Sessions)", "Birmingham.(Sessions)", 
"Leeds.(Sessions)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```